# ItemAdded how to detect if the item being added is the documentset itself or a file into the document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a document library with an itemadded event receiver. Items in the document library are document sets.

when I create an item in the document library, the item added is executed. However that logic, I want to execute it only for the document set itself and not when I add a file INTO the document set.

the following code works fine when creating the document set, but the line:

```
string recurrent = item[Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSRECURRENT_NAME].ToString();
```

throw object reference exception when the event receiver is executed when a file is uploaded to the document set

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("AgendaPointsProposedEvents", "ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "BEGIN");
            base.ItemAdded(properties);
            try
            {
                base.EventFiringEnabled = false;

                SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;
                SPItemEventDataCollection afterProperties = properties.AfterProperties;
                string listName = item.ParentList.RootFolder.Name;

                string recurrent = item[Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSRECURRENT_NAME].ToString();
                bool recurrentBln = bool.Parse(recurrent);
                if (recurrentBln)
                {
                    #region NLNSSV-169
                    // If the user selects recurrent the agenda proposed item cant have an associated meeting.
                    // Also the security is reset to its initial state.
                    properties.ListItem[Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_MEETING_NAME] = null;
                    properties.List.ResetRoleInheritance();
                    properties.ListItem.Update();
                    #endregion
                }
                else
                {
                    #region NLNSSV-184
                    // NLNSSV-184
                    // Proposed meeting points should be visible to other departments as soon as they are added to a meeting. 
                    // An event handler should change the authentication on the item level when a meeting point is added to (or removed from!) the meeting.
                    // This also needs a change in the views and screens..
                    SPFieldLookup sp = item.GetLookupField(MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_MEETING_NAME);
                    string meetingname = afterProperties.GetValueAsString("Meeting");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(meetingname))
                    {
                        RoleDefRead = SecurityHelper.GetRoleDefinition(properties.Web, Constants.PERMISSIONLEVEL_READ);
                        DepartmentCORUsersGroup = properties.Web.SiteGroups[MeetingsCommon.Constants.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_DEPARTMENTCORUSERS_NAME];
                        DepartmentFINUsersGroup = properties.Web.SiteGroups[MeetingsCommon.Constants.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_DEPARTMENTFINUSERS_NAME];
                        DepartmentMSCUsersGroup = properties.Web.SiteGroups[MeetingsCommon.Constants.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_DEPARTMENTMSCUSERS_NAME];
                        DepartmentOPIUsersGroup = properties.Web.SiteGroups[MeetingsCommon.Constants.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_DEPARTMENTOPIUSERS_NAME];
                        DepartmentRDSUsersGroup = properties.Web.SiteGroups[MeetingsCommon.Constants.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_DEPARTMENTRDSUSERS_NAME];
                        DepartmentSALUsersGroup = properties.Web.SiteGroups[MeetingsCommon.Constants.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_DEPARTMENTSALUSERS_NAME];

                        bool isProposed = item.TaxonomyFieldValueIsGivenValue(properties.AfterProperties, MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSTATUS_NAME, MeetingsCommon.Constants.TERMVALUE_AGENDAPOINTSTATUS_PROPOSED, 1033);
                        if (isProposed)
                        {

                            #region Change permissions in COR items
                            if (listName.Equals(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTSPROPOSEDCOR_NAME))
                            {
                                item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentFINUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentMSCUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentOPIUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentRDSUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentSALUsersGroup, false); // Read   
                            }
                            #endregion

                            #region Change permissions in FIN items
                            if (listName.Equals(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTSPROPOSEDFIN_NAME))
                            {
                                item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentCORUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentMSCUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentOPIUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentRDSUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentSALUsersGroup, false); // Read   
                            }
                            #endregion

                            #region Change permissions in MSC items
                            if (listName.Equals(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTSPROPOSEDMSC_NAME))
                            {
                                item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentCORUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentFINUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentOPIUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentRDSUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentSALUsersGroup, false); // Read   
                            }
                            #endregion

                            #region Change permissions in OPI items
                            if (listName.Equals(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTSPROPOSEDOPI_NAME))
                            {
                                item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentCORUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentFINUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentMSCUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentRDSUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentSALUsersGroup, false); // Read   
                            }
                            #endregion

                            #region Change permissions in RDS items
                            if (listName.Equals(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTSPROPOSEDRDS_NAME))
                            {
                                item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentCORUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentFINUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentMSCUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentOPIUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentSALUsersGroup, false); // Read   
                            }
                            #endregion

                            #region Change permissions in SAL items
                            if (listName.Equals(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTSPROPOSEDSAL_NAME))
                            {
                                item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentCORUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentFINUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentMSCUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentOPIUsersGroup, false); // Read
                                SecurityHelper.AddToRoleAssignment(RoleDefRead, properties.Web, item, DepartmentRDSUsersGroup, false); // Read   
                            }
                            #endregion
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        item.ResetRoleInheritance();
                    }
                    #endregion
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("AgendaPointsProposedEvents", "ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)", ex);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                base.EventFiringEnabled = true;
            }
            Logger.LogDebug("AgendaPointsProposedEvents", "ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)", "END");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

THe idea is to detect the contentype because sometimes a list might have different content types and you want the code to execute only for one contenttype.

easy:

```
 string contentTypeName = properties.ListItem.ContentType.Name;
            if (contentTypeName == "contentypename")
            {
```